# Spring-Integration- resthttp

Tags: spring-integration

```
  <!-- Inbound/Outbound Channels -->
    <int:channel id="serviceSearchRequest" />
    <int:channel id="serviceSearchResponse" />


    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundEmployeeSearchRequestGateway"
        supported-methods="GET, POST" request-channel="serviceSearchRequest"
        reply-channel="serviceSearchResponse"
        mapped-response-headers="Content-Type" 
        path="XXX/service/search" request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
        reply-timeout="5000">
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>
```

In the above configuration if I want to externalize the value of path i.e If I want to fetch the value from a property file, how to achieve this?

**The modified configuration**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm" xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">
<!-- This file is the context file for rest http call. The inbound and out bound call to data service will be defined here -->


    <int:annotation-config />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:resthttpurl.properties"/>

    <!-- Inbound/Outbound Channels -->
    <int:channel id="serviceSearchRequest" />
    <int:channel id="serviceSearchResponse" />
    <int:channel id="urlFormation" />

    <!-- The inbound gateway for data service http call -->
    <int-http:inbound-gateway id="inboundEmployeeSearchRequestGateway"
        supported-methods="GET, POST" request-channel="urlFormation"
        reply-channel="serviceSearchResponse" mapped-response-headers="Content-Type"
        path="${inboundpath}" request-payload-type="java.lang.String"
        reply-timeout="5000">
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>
    <!--  path="XXX/service/search" -->

    <!-- The outbound gateway for data service  http call-->
    <int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="serviceSearchRequest"
        reply-channel="serviceSearchResponse" url-expression="@DynamicURLFormationBean.getUrlFor(headers)"
        http-method="POST" expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
        mapped-response-headers="Content-Type" />


    <int:router input-channel="urlFormation" ref="URLRouter"
        method="routeURL" />
    <!-- This is a router call for future use -->
    <bean id="URLRouter" class="com.self.myprj.integration.XXX.restservice.URLRouter" />
    <!-- This bean will create a rest url of data service baed on the path variable of inbound gateway-->
    <bean id="DynamicURLFormationBean" class="com.self.myprj.integration.XXX.restservice.DynamicURLFormation" />
    <!--url="http://localhost:8080/proj/service/avgWaitTime123.json" -->
</beans>
```

The property file **content:resthttpurl.properties** is under resources folder **inboundpath=XXX/service/search**

**The stack trace :**

```
[localhost-startStop-1][org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/resthttpurl.properties]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/resthttpurl.properties]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:142)
    ... 16 more
11:02:41.047 DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1][org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@503538: defining beans [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#0,org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.methodSecurityMetadataSourceAdvisor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.security.filterChains,org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy,org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl#0,org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl#0,org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0,org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy#0,org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler#0,org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased#1,org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0,org.springframework.security.web.access.DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint#0,org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0,org.springframework.security.userDetailsServiceFactory,org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0,org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0,org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher#0,org.springframework.security.authenticationManager,jasyptStringDigester,passwordEncoder,channelInitializer,$autoCreateChannelCandidates,IntegrationConfigurationBeanFactoryPostProcessor,integrationEvaluationContext,org.springframework.integration.expression.IntegrationEvaluationContextAwareBeanPostProcessor#0,integrationGlobalProperties,integrationHeaderChannelRegistry,globalChannelInterceptorProcessor,toStringFriendlyJsonNodeToStringConverter,converterRegistrar,integrationConversionService,DefaultConfiguringBeanFactoryPostProcessor,datatypeChannelMessageConverter,messageBuilderFactory,org.springframework.integration.internalMessagingAnnotationPostProcessor,org.springframework.integration.internalPublisherAnnotationBeanPostProcessor,org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#0,serviceSearchRequest,serviceSearchResponse,urlFormation,inboundEmployeeSearchRequestGateway,org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler#0,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#1,URLRouter,DynamicURLFormationBean,org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#1,sftpSessionFactory,defaultSftpSessionFactory,sftpInbondAdapter.source,org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger#0,sftpInbondAdapter,receiveChannel,org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#2,inputChannel,org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler#0,sftpOutboundAdapter,org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer#3,org.springframework.integration.file.remote.handler.FileTransferringMessageHandler#1,org.springframework.scheduling.support.PeriodicTrigger#1,clientFactory,logger,org.springframework.integration.handler.LoggingHandler#0,logger.adapter,org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.WireTap#0,org.springframework.integration.channel.interceptor.GlobalChannelInterceptorWrapper#0,startCaseAdapter,startCase,org.springframework.integration.config.ServiceActivatorFactoryBean#0,startCaseService,mqttCaseService,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.enhancedConfigurationProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
11:02:41.047 ERROR [localhost-startStop-1][org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/resthttpurl.properties]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/resthttpurl.properties]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:142)
    ... 16 more
Jan 03, 2015 11:02:41 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Could not load properties; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/resthttpurl.properties]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:265)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:162)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/resthttpurl.properties]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:141)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource.getInputStream(EncodedResource.java:143)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderUtils.fillProperties(PropertiesLoaderUtils.java:98)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.loadProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertiesLoaderSupport.mergeProperties(PropertiesLoaderSupport.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.java:142)
    ... 16 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use normal Spring property placeholders...

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:com/foo/my.properties"/>

path="${my.path}"
```

**EDIT**:

When running in a servlet context, the file has to be located somewhere in the web context, such as...

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:WEB-INF/resthttpurl.properties"/>
```

...with your current configuration, the file would have to be located alongside the WEB-INF directory.

If you want the properties file outside of the war file, you need to put it somewhere on the app server's classpath that is visible to the war classloader hierarchy, or use `file:/somewhere/on/the/filesystem/resthttpurl.properties`.

Comment: It is failing to load the property from properties file

Comment: You need to provide more information; show the modified configuration, properties file and the exact error you are getting.

Comment: The modified configuration

Comment: Edited my answer to explain how web classpaths work.

Comment: Yes,Gary ..it worked, The solution is we should provide all the property configuration in the parent context xml file if we have multiple configuration and multiple context file