# MQTT- Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration

I am trying to run the Sample **`MQTT-SPring integration`** project . How ever I have modified some the configuration details to fetch from property file . And trying connect to message broker from the **`runMQTT.java`** file.

**Code snippet are as follow**

```
MQTT-Context.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:int-mqtt="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mqtt"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mqtt http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mqtt/spring-integration-mqtt-4.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd">


    <bean id="clientFactory"
        class="org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory">
        <property name="userName" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
        <property name="serverURIs" value="${serveruri}"></property>
    </bean>

    <!-- intercept and log every message -->
    <int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger"
        level="ERROR" />
    <int:wire-tap channel="logger" />
    <!-- Mark the auto-startup="true" for starting MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter from configuration  -->
    <int-mqtt:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="startCaseAdapter" client-id="clientId" url="${mqttbrokerurl}"
        topics="topic" channel="startCase" auto-startup="true"  />
    <int:channel id="startCase" />


    <int:service-activator id="startCaseService"
        input-channel="startCase" ref="mqttCaseService" method="startCase" />

    <bean id="mqttCaseService" class="com.XXX.integration.ieg.mqtt.MqttCaseService" />
</beans>
```

The **`properties(mqttbrokerurl, serveruri)`** are loaded from root context

**RunMQTT**

```
package com.XXX.integration.ieg.mqtt;

import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttClient;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException;
import org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttMessage;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory;
import org.springframework.integration.mqtt.inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter;

public class RunMqtt {

    public void test() throws MqttException{
        ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/integration/mqtt/mqtt-context.xml");
        System.out.println(ac);
        MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter startCaseAdapter = (MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter)ac.getBean("startCaseAdapter");
        //Uncomment to stop the adapter manually from program
        //startCaseAdapter.start();
        //DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory mqttClient = (DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory)ac.getBean("clientFactory");
        DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory mqttClient = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();

        MqttClient mclient = mqttClient.getClientInstance("tcp://localhost:1883", "JavaSample");
        String data = "This is what I am sending in 2nd attempt";
        MqttMessage mm = new MqttMessage(data.getBytes());
        mm.setQos(1);
        mclient.connect();
        mclient.publish("topic",mm);
        mclient.disconnect();
        //Uncomment to stop the adapter manually from program
        //startCaseAdapter.stop();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws MqttException {
        new RunMqtt().test();

    }

    /*public static void main1(String[] args) {

        String topic        = "MQTT Examples";
        String content      = "Message from MqttPublishSample";
        int qos             = 2;
        String broker       = "tcp://localhost:1883";
        String clientId     = "JavaSample";
        MemoryPersistence persistence = new MemoryPersistence();

        try {
            MqttClient sampleClient = new MqttClient(broker, clientId, persistence);
            MqttConnectOptions connOpts = new MqttConnectOptions();
            connOpts.setCleanSession(true);
            System.out.println("Connecting to broker: "+broker);
            sampleClient.connect(connOpts);
            System.out.println("Connected");
            System.out.println("Publishing message: "+content);
            MqttMessage message = new MqttMessage(content.getBytes());
            message.setQos(qos);
            sampleClient.publish(topic, message);
            System.out.println("Message published");
            sampleClient.disconnect();
            System.out.println("Disconnected");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch(MqttException me) {
            System.out.println("reason "+me.getReasonCode());
            System.out.println("msg "+me.getMessage());
            System.out.println("loc "+me.getLocalizedMessage());
            System.out.println("cause "+me.getCause());
            System.out.println("excep "+me);
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
    }*/

}
```

**The root context**
The root context is as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
     <!-- This file will be the root context file for web app. All other context will be imported here -->
     <!-- Security context . Now the spring security with basic authentication implemented. OAuth2 will be implemented -->
    <import resource="security-config.xml" />
    <!-- rest service call context -->
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/rest/applicationContext-http-int.xml"/>
    <!--  Sftp context-->
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/sftp/SftpInboundReceive-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/sftp/SftpOutboundTransfer-context.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/sftp/SftpOutboundTransfer-poll.xml"/>
    <!--  mqtt context-->
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/spring/integration/mqtt/mqtt-context.xml"/>


    <!--Component scan base package  -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.XXX.integration.ieg"/>
    <!-- All the property configuration moved to parent context file to solve the propert not found exception -->
        <context:property-placeholder order="1"
        location="classpath:/sftpuser.properties, classpath:/sftpfile.properties,classpath:/resthttp.properties, classpath:/mqtt.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>

</beans>
```

**In this case either mqtt or sftp or resthttp property loading is failing. Please help to resolve**

**stacktrace**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ${mqttbrokerurl}
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttConnectOptions.validateURI(MqttConnectOptions.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttAsyncClient.<init>(MqttAsyncClient.java:260)
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.core.DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory.getAsyncClientInstance(DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory.java:119)
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.connectAndSubscribe(MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:189)
    at org.springframework.integration.mqtt.inbound.MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.doStart(MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:770)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.XXX.integration.ieg.mqtt.RunMqtt.test(RunMqtt.java:18)
    at com.XXX.integration.ieg.mqtt.RunMqtt.main(RunMqtt.java:39)
```

**The properties file**
**mqtt.properties**
mqttbrokerurl=tcp://172.18.128.150:1883

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742914/spring-integration-resthttp/27744030#27744030). When running in a web app, the classpath is relative to the web context.

Answer (score 1):

According to StackTrace your property-placeholders aren't resolved and that's just because you don't have `<context:property-placeholder>` for your properties file.

Even if you say that it is:

> The properties(mqttbrokerurl, serveruri) are loaded from root context

I don't see that stuff in your code:

1. You show only `MQTT-Context.xml`
2. Your `RunMqtt` starts only that context:

   ```
   new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/integration/mqtt/mqtt-context.xml");
   ```

So, fix, please, those issues and come back to us with further progress.

Comment: The root context is as follow

Comment: No problem! But as I said: you don't load it from your `RunMqtt`, just `mqtt-context.xml`

Comment: And you should be sure that `classpath:/mqtt.properties` is correct path and your properties files are located in the root. Otherwise you should specify the full path as you do that for contexts in the `<import>`.

Comment: M-m-m. Doesn't this work for you? `classpath:/mqtt.properties`. I mean without slash

Comment: Please, switch on `DEBUG` for `org.springframewrok` and take a look in the logs what `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer` says about your files.

Comment: This was property loading issue. When debugged, the ${mqttbrokerurl} was not loading. trying to fix. Will update you once done. Thanx Artem